# Knockout KendoUI Grid - Hidden column using observable

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, grid, hide

Is there a way to hide column in the grid using an observable in knockout??

```
 var isHidden = ko.observable(false);

//Want to change based on some logic
isHidden(true);

columns: [
            { field: 'SomeColumn', title: 'Some Column header', hidden: isHidden },

        ]
```

At the moment this is not working. Any ideas??

Comment: You're going to need a custom binding handler. https://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need to use an template like :

```
 var isHidden = ko.observable(false);
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.dataItems= ko.observableArray([
        { some columns: "10", hidden: isHidden},

    ]);

};

//Want to change based on some logic
isHidden(true);
```

Your html you will need to use somthing like this

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: dataItems, rowTemplate: 'yourHiddenTemplate',  useKOTemplates: true }"> </div>

<script id="yourHiddenTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="visible:hidden ">
       //other html
    </div>
</script>
```

Just an idea, hope that he